# rails_config の環境変数が反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**実行環境**

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.6
```

環境変数を定義する Gem として有名な [config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) を使用しています

`bundle install` で config をインストールして

```
$ rails g config:install
  create  config/initializers/rails_config.rb
  create  config/settings.yml
  create  config/settings.local.yml
  create  config/settings
  create  config/settings/development.yml
  create  config/settings/production.yml
  create  config/settings/test.yml
  append  .gitignore
```

を実行し環境変数を書いておく yml ファイルを作成しました
しかし

```
$ vi config/settings.yml
twitter:
  follow_target_name: 'mossmoss'
  text: 'mossmossmossmossmoss'
  url : 'http://mossmossmossmossmoss.com/'
```

として環境変数を取得しようとすると `nil` となっていまいます

```
$ rails c
> Settings.twitter
=> nil
> Settings
=> #<Config::Options>
```

ドキュメント通りにやったのですがなぜ どこかで環境変数の取得方法が間違っているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

直接の質問の回答ではないのですが、[dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)というgemもありまして、私はいつもそれを使っているのですが、環境変数をrails内に設定するということであればそちらを使ってもできると思います。
`.env`という名前のファイルを使って、シェル変数のように環境変数にしたい情報を設定するだけです。

```
S3_BUCKET=YOURS3BUCKET
SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE
```

この設定が済むと、railsプロジェクトのどこでも（多分）以下のように記述して環境変数を取ってこれるようになると思います。

```
  s3 = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
```

configをお使いとのことですので、そちらを使うのでも一向に問題ないと思いますが、もしどうしても行き詰まってしまうようなら(そういうことはないでしょうが)、こちらを試してみるのも悪くないと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
dotenv もいいですよね。使ったことがあります。rails_config を使っている知人がいて、こっちの環境では予想通りに動かなかったので質問してみました。私も正直 culさんのようにdotenv派ですよ

Comment: dotenv とライバルに当たる figaro というのをご存知ですか？ config/application.yml に yml 文法でAPIキーやデータベースのパスワードを保存しておくことができます。個人的には yml に慣れているのでこちらをつかうことが多いです。やれることは dotenv とほぼ同じですよ。 https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: figaroは知りませんでした。私もyamlはわかるので次のプロジェクト作成時に試してみようと思います。

Comment: おたがいがんばりましょう(｀･ω･´)ゞ

Comment: dotenvを使う理由でひとつだけポジティブと思える部分もありますね。それは`rails new`コマンドの実行後のDB接続の設定やその他gemfile記述を自動化したいときに、シェルスクリプトでその自動化スクリプトを書く場合です(シェルスクリプトで`.env`ファイルも出力する、ということですね)。`sed`や`awk`を使うなら`.env`ファイルの記述の仕方の方が親和性が高いというか、割と簡単にできると思います。実際、私はそのようにしています。

Comment: メモメモ・・・なるほどそれは便利！タメになります！

Answer (score 1):

spring使ってませんか? (Rails4以降ならデフォルトで使用します)
config/initializers/以下にファイルを追加・変更したあとはbundle exec spring stop しましょう。

```
% bundle exec spring status
Spring is running:

71694 spring server | myapp | started 8 secs ago
71697 spring app    | myapp | started 8 secs ago | development mode
% vi Gemfile
% bundle
% vi config/settings.yml
% bin/rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 72273
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
>> Settings
=> #<Config::Options>
>> Settings.twitter
=> nil
>> ^D
% bundle exec spring stop
Spring stopped.
% bin/rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 72436
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
>> Settings.twitter
=> #<Config::Options follow_target_name="mossmoss">
```